# Не правильно работает проверка

Tags: android, kotlin

Писал проверку файлов..

Пробовал по разному, не получается, туплю.

Сама проверка работает, но вот даже если запускается обновление файлов, то код ниже (запуск клиента) выполняется. А мне надо чтоб он прерывался.

```
ApiService.getInstance().apiService.getFiles(App.getInstance().URL_FILES_DATA)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Files>?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<Files>?>, response: Response<ArrayList<Files>?>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        var check = true
                        Thread {
                            for (i in response.body()!!.indices) {
                                val file = File(Config.GAME_PATH + response.body()!![i].path)
                                if (!file.exists() || !Utils.checkMD5(this@InstallActivity, response.body()!![i].size, file)) {
                                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                                        val bundle = Bundle()
                                        bundle.putInt("type", Config.DOWNLOADING_GAME_FILES)
                                        check = false
                                        binding.progressBar.isIndeterminate = false
                                        PagesManager.getInstance().startPage(this@InstallActivity, PagesManager.Pages.UPDATE, bundle, true)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(check) {
                                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                                    Toasty.success(this@InstallActivity, "тут должен быть запуск клиента игры").show()
                                }
                            }
                        }.start()
                    }
```

Comment: Ну а как ты его прерываешь?

Comment: прерывал обычным break'ом, все равно производится запуск

Comment: `check = false` присваиваете в главном потоке через `post`. То есть когда нибудь, когда главный поток будет свободен. И случиться это может позже, чем выполнится проверка `if(check)`. Перенесите присвоение в блок `if {}` (выше или ниже блока `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {}`), чтобы присвоение выполнялось в том же потоке, что и проверка

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему заменив for на while. Для данной проверки он больше подходит.